# Unable to execute githooks on some windows machines

Tags: windows, githooks

I had compiled a golang code and got a binary out of it. This binary was the pre-commit git hook. 
However this git hook does work on some windows machines and it does not work on some windows machines. I use GitBash for running git commands.

I don't know what the issue might be. I did run it on Windows 10 and it worked on one of the machines and didn't work on another one.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your script is executable. To check whether the file is executable, run this in your terminal

```
ls -l /path/of/file
```

If you find it as non executable, Use this command for making it as an executable.

```
chmod +x /path/of/file
```

If you don't know what is `ls -l`. Please go through here. https://askubuntu.com/a/528433